# How to import values of a JSON to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a JSON file gugu.json that looks like this:

```
{
"key1": {
          "value1": "normal",
          "value2": [
                     "PogU"
                    ]
        },
"key2": ...
}
```

I want to put all the contents of the JSON file into the table

`KEKW(value1 text, value2 text, ...)`.

I already tried many thing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE gugu(
 data json
);

\copy gugu FROM 'gugu.json';

SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(null::KEKW, (SELECT data->'key1' FROM gugu));
```

But as you can see I just don't know how I would get the "second level" of JSON in the table?

Comment: What do you want to do with the array for `value2`? Where should the elements there go? or does that always contains exactly one element?

Comment: The keys are not in the table, they just seperate the rows.

Comment: I am talking about the `"PogU"` value, what do you want to do with that array?

Comment: It should just show as an array inside the specific field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unnest the first level, and the second level in two steps:

Use `jsonb_each()` instead:

```
select d.val ->> 'value1' as value1,
       d.val ->> 'value2' as value2
from gugu g
  cross join jsonb_each(g.data) as d(ky,val);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a71064d0b8c055cb72e8265857d30e6)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @NuTa If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.